# Delete an view from the MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recycler view app in which it takes data from user and set it on a recycler view I want that when user will click on that view an alert dialog box will open and it will ask that should he wand to delete or not. If yes the view will deleted. Can any one help me how to implement that?

here is the main activity code I have

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var todolist= mutableListOf<Todo>()
//            Todo("c",false),
           /* Todo("java",true),
            Todo("python",false),
            Todo("c#",false),
            Todo("c++",true),
            Todo("json",false),
            Todo("web dev",true),
            Todo("kotlin",true)*/

        val adapter=TodoAdapter(todolist)
        rvTodos.adapter=adapter
        rvTodos.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener{
            val title=etTodo.text.toString()
            if(title==""){
                val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                builder.setTitle("Alart")
                builder.setMessage("Title can't be empty")

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
                    // Handle positive button click

                }

                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, which ->
                    Toast.makeText(this,"set title first",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                val alertDialog = builder.create()
                alertDialog.show()

            }
            else{
                val todo=Todo(title,false)
                todolist.add(todo)
                adapter.notifyItemInserted(todolist.size-1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is the adapter class

```
class TodoAdapter(val todos: List<Todo>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViweholder>(){
    inner class TodoViweholder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViweholder {
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo,parent,false)
        return TodoViweholder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViweholder, position: Int) {
            holder.itemView.apply {
               tvTitle.text=todos[position].title
                cbDone.isChecked=todos[position].isChecked
            }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

XML for recycler structure

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/structure"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cbDone"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbDone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is the main activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvTodos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/etTodo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:text="New Todo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTodo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="set title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I am not convinced you want to remove a view. Shouldn't you remove the entry from underlying dataset instead?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that you need to show popup on each view from the recycler view and will decide whether that view need to delete or not.

To achieve this, you can add a click listener inside `TodoAdapter#onBindViewHolder()` class for each ViewHolder item like as follow:

```
holder.itemView.apply {
  tvTitle.text=todos[position].title
  cbDone.isChecked=todos[position].isChecked
  clickListener = OnClickListener {
    // <code to build and show your expected dialog here on view click>

    // In dialog builder, on button click remove entry from the adapter list and notify it like as follow.   
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, which ->
    todos.remove(holder.getPosition())
    notifyDatasetChanged()
  } 
}
```